# Brand-able p2p video chat / conferencing service (one-on-one)

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for something that would facilitate a private video chat between two cameras. Ideally it would be a hosted service (like Viddler) that can be implemented into a site and branded.

I've read Adobe Stratus is the technology behind chatroulette - the need is for something that has similar functionality but privately and not random - TinyChat is pretty close but isn't brand-able or able to be embedded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: http://www.hbrlabs.com/ . They have several branded experiences, so I assume they offer the white label services.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/

It's built specifically for education, but it's free and open source, it's brandable, and includes an API to integrate it into your website

Answer (score 0):

Try this free, hosted business collaboration tool; Banckle [Enterprise IM](http://banckle.com/apps/enterprise-im/default.html) for secure two-way video chat. Juts connect webcams and go.

Comment: The link you gave is no longer working. I clicked on it and laned on an offline page.